# Correction chart view with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like you to help me with a couple of issues that I have.

When I set the picture I have two problems.

First: I would like to know how to suppress the hour and minute leaves and leave only the tooltip date.

Secondly: I would like to know why the graph below, which is taking 0 values, its leaving red marks when it doesn't have to leave anything.

Thanks, and sorry for my English, I used by Google Translate!

[image]

Edit:

Code:

```
var yAxis = [{
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Cierre'
    },
    type: 'logarithmic',
    height: '65%',
    lineWidth: 2,
    offset: 40
}, {
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3
    },
    title: {
        text: 'RSC Mansfield'
    },
    top: '70%',
    height: '15%',
    offset: 40,
    lineWidth: 2
}, {
    labels: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -3
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Atlas'
    },
    top: '90%',
    height: '10%',
    offset: 40,
    lineWidth: 2
}];
var series = [{
    type: type,
    name: 'Data',
    id: 'price',
    data: scope.chart.data,
    color: '#000000',
    lineWidth: 2,
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    }
}, {
    type: 'coloredline',
    name: 'WMA 30',
    data: getWMA(scope.chart.wma),
    lineWidth: 1,
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    }
}, {
    type: 'flags',
    data: scope.chart.dividend,
    onSeries: 'price',
    color: '#E68A00'
}, {
    type: 'area',
    name: 'RSC Mansfield',
    data: scope.chart.mansfield,
    yAxis: 1,
    color: '#009900',
    fillColor: '#009900',
    negativeColor: '#CC0000',
    negativeFillColor: '#CC0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    }
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Atlas',
    data: scope.chart.atlas,
    yAxis: 2,
    color: '#CC0000',
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    }
}];
$('.chart-container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: $('.chart-container').width() > 480,
        selected: 4
    },
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    yAxis: yAxis,
    series: series,
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold: 3000 //set it to a larger threshold, it is by default to 1000
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: post your code here, google translate...so cool!

Answer (score 2):

1. Tooltip issue - you could use:

a) [tooltip.headerFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.headerFormat)

or
b) [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter)

2. Columns issue - setting `borderWidth: 1` will cover with border the point.
   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzv9d4qs/

This looks like a bug, so I reported it here - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5146

Comment: Kacper's answer is excellent, check also this example http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/hk97gvox/ to set up tooltip